# How to point subdomain to another subdomain?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I want to point a subdomain test.example.com to another subdomain hi.hello.com. How would I go about this in the DNS settings (CNAME, ALIAs, etc).

I tried doing it but it doesn't route through and I'm not sure how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Both `CNAME` and `ALIAS` will work:

http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/

What you're probably facing is a DNS cache propagation issue.